# How to stop ReportLab appending unwanted character to barcode?

Tags: python, pdf, barcode, reportlab

I create a pdf-page with barcodes on it using ReportLab. Everything works except that when I scan one of the barcodes it appends a character. For example when I try to scan 700124 I get 700124A, 700224 becomes 700224B, etc. I do not want these characters to be appended. Does anyone know how to stop this? I could not find any documentation about this. I use the following Python code:

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("barcode_example.pdf", pagesize=A4)

code_list = ['700124', '700224', '700324', '700424', '700524', '700624', '700724', '700824', '700924']

x = 1 * mm
y = 280 * mm
x1 = 6.4 * mm
r = 0

for code in code_list:
    barcode = code39.Standard39(code, barHeight=26, stop=1)
    barcode.drawOn(c, x, y)
    x1 = x + 6.4 * mm
    y = y - 5 * mm
    c.drawString(x1, y, code)
    x = x
    y = y - 25 * mm

    if int(y) < 0:
        if r != 3:
            x = x + 50 * mm
            y = 280 * mm
            r = r + 1
        else:
            c.showPage()
            x = 1 * mm
            y = 280 * mm
            x1 = 6.4 * mm
            r = 0

c.save()
```

Comment: Can you test if it's not your scanner that adds the character?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) tells me a *checksum* is optional. Perhaps (1) your Python code is adding it, and (2) your reader does not recognize it as such. Your (2...) examples behave like a checksum.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The Python code is not adding it. Also the scanner does not add the character. I have now done done it by generating the barcodes as images and then letting ReportLab work with those.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the user claims it's not being added, by default the reportlab barcode library automatically adds the checksum.

To avoid the checksum character, initialize your barcode with the parameter checksum=0, like so:

```
barcode = code39.Standard39(code, barHeight=26, stop=1, checksum=0)
```